# Why Text_Changed event of TextBox does not fire when we change its text programmatically?

Tags: c#, events, textbox, textchanged

I have designed a softkeypad and changing textbox text programmatically such as

```
myKeypad.getControl.Text += "Char";
```

but textbox textchanged event does not fire.
How can I solve this problem?
Is it possible that we can create custom textChanged and KeyPressed Events which can fire by changing text or key press by softkeypad programmatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be triggered.

From MSDN [Control.TextChanged Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.textchanged.aspx):

> This event is raised if the Text property is changed by either a programmatic modification or user interaction.

Where are you adding the Event Handler?

Comment: ! Both TextBox and Keypad are contained by a form and TextBoxTextChanged Event also included in this form. Custom Control 'Keypad' can access the textbox and change its text in its own class. (Sorry for bad English)

Comment: The event is most likely consumed by your Custom Control if I had to guess. You should set up some break points inside your TextChanged event of your controls. I'm sure you'll figure out what is wrong rather quickly.